# What is wrong with my Christmas flower?

Tags: houseplants, flowers

Can someone identify what is wrong with this flower and what should I do to take a better care of it
[image][image]

Comment: Did you buy this recently for Christmas, maybe at a supermarket? Have you repotted it, and does that pot  its in have a drainage hole in the bottom?

Comment: Yes I bought this one about a month ago. I repotted it and it has a drainage hole in it. The place where I bought it from didnt have much light and this flower was doing great there. Should I change the location of it ( maybe to a darker room )?

Comment: No!  Don't go to a darker room.  I understand that you might think lower light is better because of the lighting in the store but trust me, the store was and is temporary. Is this potting medium? How often do you water?  Either you went on a short vacation and this plant wasn't watered or you are watering this plant way too much.  Did you put any gravel or rocks below the soil in this pot?  This isn't a flower...these are specialized leaves, cool, huh?  Poisonous to dogs and cats fyi.  Keep in bright light but not direct sunlight.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you probably realise, millions of these plants (Poinsettia) are grown specially for the Christmas market, usually sold relatively cheaply at many outlets such as supermarkets and also garden centres (where they'll be more expensive!). They will have been 'hot housed' to get them ready for sale, and by that I mean grown in massive greenhouses with perfect lighting, moisture and most particularly, temperature. When you buy your plant, its already been shipped to wherever its going to be sold, and probably exposed to cold air as its moved from delivery truck to the store; then you buy it and expose it to cold air again  as you  take it to your car. This often means we're lucky if our Poinsettias make it to  Christmas Day and still look healthy, so don't feel too bad about what's happened to yours.

They don't appreciate sun, they just like good daylight; they loathe temperature  fluctuations, temperatures below 15deg C, draughts (so near windows isn't great), being placed near a heat source, heavy, slow draining soil and dry air. They  need to dry out a little between waterings, which means the surface of the soil in the pot should feel just a bit dry at the surface when you water. When you do water, water well, but never  leave any outer pot or tray full of water - empty it after 30 minutes so that the plant is not sitting in water.

Now  that yours has drooped, it may well not recover, unfortunately - you may find all the green leaves drop off and you're left with just bare stalks with red bracts (the red 'leaves', the flowers are the tiny bud like objects in the middle) at the top, which isn't a terribly attractive look. However, although most people just throw these plants away after Christmas, it is possible to get them growing again and even to produce those red bracts for next year, but it is a bit of a performance. The way to start the process is, in fact, to let your plant dry out  so that the leaves wilt and drop off; as yours has already started doing that, it might be worth a try. After the leaves have dropped off (including the red bracts) move it to a cool dry place and keep the soil just slightly moist until spring. Then, once spring arrives, prune it down to 4-6 inches high and move to a warmer, brighter spot. You should see growth beginning, at which point start watering as normal again - treat as a normal houseplant, fertilize every couple of weeks, and then later, around September, you will need to give it 12 hours of complete darkness daily for 8 weeks to get the red bracts to form. Full, detailed instructions here https://www.wyevalegardencentres.co.uk/tips-and-advice_how-to-care-for-poinsettia

Comment: Great answer, Bamboo.  Wow.

Comment: It's almost impossible to get a poinsettia to reflower and still be a nice looking plant.  All I see is hundreds of straggly looking with a puff of leaves on the end.

Comment: @kevinsky - I did the procedure once, decades ago, the results were actually quite reasonable, but its too much of an effort when they're so cheap to buy...